# Why isn't Angular calling registerOnChange in my implementation of ControlValueAccessor?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to implement a custom form control component inside a template-drive form in Angular 4. Because I want it to integrate nicely with the parent form, I am trying to implement it as a ControlValueAccessor. I have followed the guides I could find but Angular is not cooperating. According to the documentation, it should be calling my implementation of `registerOnChange()`, but it doesn't. Why is that?

```
/* editor-clause.component.ts */
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
import { QueryClause } from '../../../../models/query-clause';
import { Input, Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: EditorClauseComponent,
    multi: true,
  }],
  selector: 'editor-clause',
  templateUrl: './editor-clause.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editor-clause.component.css']
})
export class EditorClauseComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input('clause') clause: QueryClause;
  parentOnChange: any;

  writeValue(_obj: any): void {
    return;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    // This never gets printed and I don't know why
    console.log('Registering parent change tracking');
    this.parentOnChange = () => {
      console.log('Saw a change. Invoking parent function');
      fn();
    };
  }

  registerOnTouched(_fn: any): void {
    return;
  }

}
```

The containing parent form looks something like:

```
<form #queryBuilderForm="ngForm">

    <p>Form instructions here</p>

    <editor-clause *ngFor="let clause of clauses" [clause]="clause"></editor-clause>

    <button (click)="addClause()" id="add-query-clause-button">Add clause</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Your component has no relations with angular form control. You should add either ngModel or formControlName to it

Comment: @yurzui please elaborate. Where do I add that?

Comment: in your form template, you should add an `ngModel` attribute directive

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As explained in the article [Never again be confused when implementing ControlValueAccessor in Angular forms](https://indepth.dev/posts/1055/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms) the `ControlValueAccessor` is an intermediary between native control and Angular's form control:

[image]

The Angular form control can be created automatically by applying `NgModel` directive like this:

```
<editor-clause ngModel *ngFor="let clause of clauses" [clause]="clause"></editor-clause>
```

Or manually in the component and then bound to a control using `formControl` directive:

```
export class EditorClauseComponent ... {
    myControl = new FormControl();
```

Template:

```
<editor-clause [formControl]="myControl" *ngFor="let clause of clauses" [clause]="clause"></editor-clause>
```

Comment: If I am using the `EditorClauseComponent` to control the value of `clause`, should I be passing it in with ngModel, like `[(ngModel)]="clause"`? I think I am cheating right now, since it is not actually setting a value for it in the form.

Comment: @Stewart, can you also show the code for the containing parent component?

Comment: It's 500+ lines so I will spare you that and re-read your tutorial :) thanks

Comment: @Stewart, all right :) maybe then ask another more specific question. Good luck

Comment: I guess my question is about how to implement the two-way binding for the component if it's a template-driven form. Do I then use `<editor-clause [(ngModel)]="clause">` and use a `value` property within that component for tracking the value for the purposes of it as a form control?

Comment: @Stewart, let me think about it. Also it'd help if you showed container component code (the relevant parts)

Comment: I am using `[formControlName]` but still it is not working...